# c#: Namespace precedence / priority? Have 2 classes with the same name

Tags: c#, namespaces, conflict

I have 2 classes, both are called the same "Product", 1 class is mine and the other belongs to somebody else.

I get a compile error in code as it appear some code is trying to use the Product from "my" class rather than "their".

I have temporary fixed this by prefixing there namespace on the lines that use the class.

I have the "using" of their class.

So whats the way to fix this, leave my prefix or reorder the namespaces... whcih should come first?

I suppose this gives me another problem... If i fix this issue and i need to reference my class then i am going to need to prefix that.

Any advise the best way to tackle this would be very helpful.

Comment: 1. You could explicitly use the Namespace, but give it a shorter name
using myNamespace = YourNamespace.OtherNamespace.Product
then you could use myNamespace.Product
2. Rename your class

Comment: If both classes are going to be used in the same code, I would fully qualify both class names as described in the answers posted below.  This way, someone reading the code would not have to remember which order the using statements were in to know which Product was being instantiated.

Comment: THanks everyone for the confirmation, this is what i suspected..Thanks... will use alias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can be explicit in your declarations, for example.

```
var myProduct = new MyCompany.MyLibrary.Product();
var otherProduct = new OtherCompany.OtherLibrary.Product();
```

You can even use the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

```
using myNS = MyCompany.MyLibrary;
...
var myProduct = new myNS.Product();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) directive.

```
using myProduct = SomeNameSpace.My;
using thierProduct = SomeNameSpace.Thier;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fully qualify your classes without using namespaces:

```
namespace.Product product = new namespace.Product();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the namespaces and class are exactly the same you're going to have to alias one of them.  If the namespaces are different another option would be to use the full path of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Using Direvctive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After the `usings` declarations declaring two(or one: just the one that is colliding)

```
/*in the usings*/
using MyProduct = MyCompanyNamespace.Product;
using TheirProduct =TheirCompany.Product;

/*some where in the code*/ 
var myProduct = new MyProduct();
var theirProduct = new TheirProduct();
```